# what are streams in Dart

Tags: dart, flutter

What is the difference between async and streams, where we should use streams instead of async, in Dart language.As descried in the official documentation stream represents the sequence of data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Async** execution is registering a callback that is called when some other computation completes.
This can be a an operating system like `file.readAsString()` , or an HTTP request to a server where the client continues executing UI rendering (or other things) and when the response from the server arrives, your code gets called to process the response.

In Dart you usually get a `Future` back from such async call, where you can register a callback using `.then(/* pass callback here */)`.

`async` and `await` is syntactic sugar so you don't need to clutter your code with `.then(...).then(...)`.

A **stream** can be sync or async, but async means something different here than the `async` explained above.

A stream is similar to a `Future` in some ways, but the callback can be called more than once if multiple events are emitted, until the sender or receiver closes the stream.

An async execution completes a `Future` once when it's done and that was it.

A stream can also be seen as iterable like an array, but where the items are pushed instead of pulled.

A main difference is also that there are many operators available for streams to map streams, fork and join multiple streams, and many more.
Many of these operators remind of methods available for collections like arrays, because as mentioned, a stream has similarities to iterables.

Streams compose well, and with the set of available operators, stream allow a kind of declarative programming which can be quite powerful, where a lot can be achived with a few streams and operators combined well.